# Manually Set enode in Parity?

Tags: parity, enode

I deleted my network/key file and want to use my old enode because it is in the chain spec, etc.  Is there a way to do this or is it cryptographically impossible?

Answer (score -2):

```
./parity  --reserved-peers supportnode.txt
```

see this wiki
https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Basic-Usage

Comment: Its better if you can explain a bit when providing an answer, rather than just posting code/ links. Quoting from eternal links might be useful if link get broken. appreciate your attempt to answer an unanswered question :)

Comment: @wliment You are answering a completely different question.  You are answering how to manually connect to a specific node.  I didn't ask that.